# DropBox API: File Browser Examples?

Tags: ruby, api, dropbox

I'm using the DropBox API (Ruby) to allow users to browse their DropBox folders/files within my web app and select a file(s) to be referenced...I'll only be storing the URL of the file within my app. With that being said, does anyone have examples of a good file browser for use within my app?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for minimalist example code, the [Dropbox Ruby SDK](https://dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) comes with an example program called `web_file_browser.rb` that you might want to look at.  It's very bare-bones, so you can't use it in your app directly, but it might help you get started.